# Where to get difficulty data for all crypto coins?

Tags: difficulty, exchange-rate

I need to get difficulty data and exchange rate for past 10 days for making a graph out of it (i.e., for all coins). Can anyone suggest where can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at [CoinWarz's API](http://www.coinwarz.com/v1/api/documentation), you can collect your own set of data for a period of time out of it (say 10 latest days, format it your own way and save it on a spreadsheet). You'll need to [generate an API key on their site](http://www.coinwarz.com/v1/api/generateapikey), and then you could either use your own scripts, or [visit the API endpoint manually](http://www.coinwarz.com/v1/api/profitability/?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY&algo=all) to collect the data, if you so desire (remember that you need your own API KEY to get the data).

Once you have the data you could generate your own graph within a spreadsheet or your  software of preference.

Recomendations: [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org) ([info](http://www.openoffice.org/documentation/manuals/oooauthors/Creating_Charts_Graphs.pdf) on graphs, [download page](http://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html)), [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org) ([info](https://help.libreoffice.org/Chart/Charts_in) on making graphs, [download page](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/)).

Here's the [reference](http://www.coinwarz.com/v1/api/documentation) for that specific API call (quoted from coinWarz's documentation)

> ***Mining Profitability API***
>
> The Mining Profitability API provides profitability data listed on CoinWarz.com. This >data can be for all coins or for specific hashing algorithms: SHA-256, Scrypt, Scrypt-N, >X11, X13, Keccak, Quark, Groestl, JHA, Blake-256, NeoScrypt, Lyra2RE
>
> ***API Endpoint***
>
> http://www.coinwarz.com/v1/api/profitability/?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY&algo=all
>
> ***API Call Usage***
>   This value will be deducted from your API usage limit each time you successfully call this API.
>
> Required Input Parameters
>   All input parameters are required and not case sensitive.
>
> **Parameter** - *Data Type* - Description
>
> **ApiKey** - *String* - Provide your approved API key for this parameter.
>
> **Algo** - *String*    - Provide one of the the following values for this parameter: 
>   all, sha-256, scrypt, scrypt-n, x11, x13, keccak, quark, groestl, jha, blake-256, >neoscrypt, lyra2re

Remember that each time you either visit the [API Endpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) or call it to fetch the info with a script, it'll count as 1 call out of your limit, as noted on their documentation.

Now the easiest way for you to collect the data if you're not into programming your own stuff, would be to use some [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) client extension for your browser such as [Postman REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/postman%20rest%20client?hl=en) (If you use a different browser look into their respective stores)

It's fairly easy to get used to and you do not need to code your own scripts.

Here's an example of how the info would be rendered for to you:

[image: Postman REST client call to CoinWarz API Endpoint]

**(remember you need to place your own API key in lieu of the placeholder "YOUR_API_KEY")**

I recommend you use the **JSON** and **PRETTY** options so the data is more human readable.

You can then export this to a [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) using this awesome tool ([JSON to CSV](http://konklone.io/json/))

This site allows you to pase the [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data and transfer each value pair to a CSV file

Here an example of how it looks:

[image: JSON to CSV in action]

Now you have a (set of, since you need multiple days) CSV file that you can use for graph creation using the aforementioned Office Suite Tools.

Hope you'll find this helpful, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an API or for just the data?
You can't really find every last coin as more are comign each and every day.
However, coinwarz or coinchoose usually have most of the data.

coinchoose has current+historic data available via json api

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your answer is in [coin warz](http://www.coinwarz.com/cryptocurrency).

Comment: YoMismo, thanks for your answer. I just added a post notice because I think you could explicitly show where on "coin warz" the OP could find the information they are looking for. Thanks!

Comment: The information is exactly in the link I posted, there you have the difficulty and the coins mined up till now. I thought there was nothing else to explain since the information is right there and if that information is posted here it would be easily outdated since it changes fast.

Comment: It seems like the OP wants to use the data for making a chart though, so they probably are looking for a way to get raw data in large amounts, not just to look at the current difficulty data that is displayed on the front page of coinwarz. I agree, though, coinwarz is a great resource for this, and posting current difficulty data would not be worthwhile as it would go out of date very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the apis given in Coinwarz documentation, it seems that there is no way of getting historic coin difficulty data.